# Modify Text in Html after webpage is ready

Tags: html, text-extraction

I've written a webpage and I want to modify the text in it without having to search for it in `html`.

I imagine a solution like this:

1. Some `script` extracts the text between `tags` (each piece of text on a new line in a file)
2. It replaces each `piece of text` with a `placeholder` in the `html` file
3. You modifiy the extracted text file, line by line
4. Then the `script` replaces each `placeholder` with the new text.

Has this been implemented? What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: I was considering writing one such script if it doesn't exist. I just replace text manually looking through html and it kills me if sections of the website need to change text. If you know one such solution in any language: Ruby, Python etc. please let me know.

Comment: I found this recently: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ or http://www.nokogiri.org/. Do you think it might work for my problem?